# Как определить начало и конец недели по текущей дате

Tags: php, дата

Ребята, вот такая у меня есть функция

```
function x_week_range($date) {
    $ts = strtotime($date);
    $start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last monday', $ts);
    return date('Y-m-d', $start)."/".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next sunday', $start));
}
```

Если я передаю `$weekdate = explode("/", x_week_range(date("2017-10-08")));`

то в `$weekdate[0]` я получаю **2017-10-08**, хотя должен был бы получить **2017-10-02**, а в `$weekdate[1]` я получаю **2017-10-15**, а хотелось бы **2017-10-08**.

Если же `$weekdate = explode("/", x_week_range(date("2017-10-07")));` то все корректно. Так как и ожидаю. 2 число это начало недели, а 8 конец.

Вопрос, что исправить в функции, что бы все корректно работало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date('w', $ts) == 0` - это последнее **воскресенье**, а не понедельник (так уж принято в америках). Ну, далее, я полагаю, все очевидно:

```
//...
$start = (date('w', $ts) == 1) ? $ts : strtotime('last monday', $ts);
//...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',time());
//$date='2019-04-16';
$dates[]= date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($date)));   
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tuesday this week', strtotime($date)));
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('wednesday this week', strtotime($date)));   
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('thursday this week', strtotime($date)));  
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('friday this week', strtotime($date)));  
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('saturday this week', strtotime($date)));
$dates[]=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week', strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]