# Получить даты текущей недели php

Tags: php, дата, datetime

необходимо вывести даты текущей недели

```
 <?php for($i = 1;$i < 7;$i++) { ?>
   <div class="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$i." day")); ?>"></div>   
 <?php } ?>
```

Так работает, но конечно же не выводит текущую дату...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить начало и конец недели по текущей дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727963/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Мне нужно это решить с помощью foreach или for все же

Comment: ну там же все есть, что вам надо. Написал ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = strtotime('monday this week');
for($i = 1;$i < 7;$i++) {?>
   <div class="<?php echo date("Y-m-d", $date); ?>"></div> 
<?php 
   $date =  strtotime('+1 day', $date);
} ?>
```

Comment: Почти идеально, только чтобы начало было с сегодняшней даты

Comment: $date = time();

Answer (score 0):

Получить текущую дату, текущий день недели. Знаем разницу в днях между сегодняшним днём недели и понедельником (понедельник - 0, вторник - 1, среда - 2 и т.д.). Зная это можно легко определить дату понедельника (отнимаем от текущей даты необходимое количество дней). Прибавляем 6 дней к понедельнику - получаем воскресенье.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $date = strtotime('monday this week');
    $dates=[];
    for($i = 0;$i < 7;$i++) {
        $dates[] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+'.$i.' day', $date));
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]